# Connecting to apache kafka API through python

Tags: python, api, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have been reading apache kafka API documentation [from here](https://kafka.apache.org/protocol.html)

this is the code that i have made in python which is TCP connection to kafka broker sitting at 9092
with all the server.properties are default for kafka

```py
import socket
import struct

# Create a TCP/IP socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

# Connect the socket to the port where the server is listening
server_address = ('localhost', 9092)
sock.connect(server_address)



#int16=2bytes=h
#int32=4bytes=i
#int64=8bytes=q


def string_to_binary(topic):

    topics=bytearray()
    topics+=struct.pack(">h",len(topic)) #INT16
    topics+=bytes(topic,"utf-8")
    return topics
request_api_key,request_api_version,correlation_id=1,0,7
headers=bytearray()
headers+=struct.pack(">hhi",request_api_key,request_api_version,correlation_id)


replica_id,max_wait_ms,min_bytes=0,10,100
body=bytearray()
body+=struct.pack(">iii",replica_id,max_wait_ms,min_bytes)



topics=bytearray()
topics+=string_to_binary("messages")# topic name
topics+=struct.pack(">iqi",1,0,10)#  partition array

request=headers+body+topics
print("data is sent out")
sock.sendall(request)
# Receive the response
response = bytearray()
while True:
    print("waiting for data")
    data = sock.recv(1024)
    print("intermediate data which is blocking")
    if not data:
        break
    response += data
print(response)
```

this code is to fetch the topic `messages` with partiton 0 and offset as 0
the output is empty and this is the screenshot from kafka broker logs at 9092
[image]

so yeah
org.apache.kafka.common.network.InvalidReceiveException: Invalid receive (size = 1919903841 larger than 104857600) so max size is 104857600
i went and changed the `socket.request.max.bytes` to `2019903841`

then this is the new error
[image]

do any one have solution for this?

Thanks in advance!

My main aim is to connect to apache kafka API.I want to fetch all the data from a particular topic in a particular offset

Answer (score 0):

> fetch all the data from a particular topic in a particular offset

You can already do this with [`kafka-python`](https://kafka-python.readthedocs.io/en/master/) `KafkaConsumer` instance by `assign`-ing a topic-partition and `seek`-ing to an offset, then `poll`-ing the data

Comment: Thanks for the reply but i have used kafka-python and confluent-kafka packages but i was exploring the kafka API and how to data is being sent and recieved in low level :)

Comment: Okay. I'm just saying that's not necessary, and you can also look at the source code for those libraries and see the exact same socket requests are made rather than doing it on your own

Comment: Yes i did the same and made the above code i just think i might be missing something over sending bytes to API

Comment: I don't know. I've never written a plain TCP Kafka client before because there's no clear optimization  benefits of doing so